# Create a 2D Matrix X[][] with letters on X axis and numbers on Y Axis

Tags: c#, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a 2D matrix like given below.
I am not able to find a way, please help me out.

A pseudo code would be very helpful.

Normal x[3][5] 2D matrix :

```
[00][01][02][03][04]
[10][11][12][13][14]
[20][21][22][23][24]
```

What I want to create is x[C][5]

```
[A0][A1][A2][A3][A4]
[B0][B1][B2][B3][B4]
[C0][C1][C2][C3][C4]
```

Comment: In what language? Most don't support custom indexing, but you can create a class that internally has a 2D array with getter and setter methods that accept letters.

Comment: @ElanHamburger C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't quite the syntax you were looking for, but I think it'll suit your needs. In order to get the behavior you want, you'll need to create a class that stores a 2D matrix and overloads the `[]` operator to accept a `char` instead of an `int`

```
public class Matrix<T> {
    private T[,] arr;

    public Matrix(int x, int y) {
        arr = new T[x, y];
    }

    public T this[char c, int i] {
        get { return arr[c - 'A', i]; }
        set { arr[c - 'A', i] = value; }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the code is actually pretty simple. It takes advantage of the fact that the `char` datatype holds the ASCII value of its letter. By subtracting away 'A', we can use 'A' as 0, 'B' as 1, etc. Then you can call your Matrix using characters like so:

```
Matrix<int> m = new Matrix<int>(3,4); // Creates a 3 x 4 matrix of ints
m['B',3] = 4;                         // m[1,3] = 4
```

**EDIT**

If you wanted to, you could also modify the constructor to accept a `char`

```
public Matrix(char x, int y) {
    arr = new T[x - 'A' + 1, y];
}
```

Note that the character you use to initialize, like an integer initializer for an array, is the *number* of entries and thus one greater than the highest index.

```
Matrix<int> m = new Matrix<int>('C',4); // Creates a 3 x 4 matrix of ints
m['B',3] = 4;                           // m[1,3] = 4
```